basis in $H^{-1}(0,1)$
It is known that $(\sin(n\pi x))_{n\ge 1}$ is an orthogonal basis in $L^2(0,1)$. My question is whether it is also a basis for $H^{-1}(0,1)$, the dual space of $H^1_0(0,1)$?
I guess it is not, but I'm not sure. In this case, can one give an explicit basis using this family?

How is that a basis? The span of those functions all have $f(0)=0.$

@ThomasAndrews every $L^2(0,1)$ function can be decomposed as Fourier expansion in $(0,1)$ ($0$ not included).
